# Javascript: Argument 1 of File constructor can't be converted to a sequence

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I'm trying to change the filename of a `File` object via javascript:

```
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="file" onchange="__func(this)">
</body>

<script>
    function __func(target)
    {
        let file = target.files[0];
            file = new File(
                file.slice(0, file.size),
                file.name,
                {type: 'text/csv'}
            );

        console.log(file);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Even if `slice` [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice) a `Blob` object, and `File` constructor [does accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) a `Blob` object as first parameter, I receive the following error:

> Argument 1 of File constructor can't be converted to a sequence.

How can I solve it?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File is itself a blob, so we can pass [file] similar to [blob] and type can be accessed by file.type

Try this

```html
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="file" onchange="__func(this)">
</body>

<script>
    function __func(target)
    {
        let file = target.files[0];
       file = new File([file], 'youRenamedIt.csv',{type:file.type});
        console.log(file);
    }
</script>
</html>
```